# How can I break apart a GraphQL Schema into multiple files in graphql-yoga

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm new to GraphQL.  I'm trying to break apart a schema.sql file into multiple files.

First question, is this a standard way of doing things with GraphQL (for example, Query.graphql, Mutation.graphql, TypeA.graphql, etc.)

Second, I thought the parameter in typeDefs (for graphql-yoga) allows me to pass an array of locations for all the schema files, but it's not working for me (See below after the code for the error I'm geting.

Here is my code in my main index.js file:

```
import { graphQLServer, GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga';
import db from '../database/db';
import Query from './resolvers/Query';
import Mutation from './resolvers/Mutation';
import Post from './resolvers/Post';
import User from './resolvers/User';
import Comment from './resolvers/Comment';
const typeDefs = [
     './schemas/query.graphql', 
     './schemas/mutation.graphql',
     './schemas/user.graphql'
];

const server = new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs: typeDefs,
    context: { db },
    resolvers: { Query, Mutation, Post, User, Comment }
});

server.start(()=> {
    console.log("Server started on localhost:4000!");
});
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Field createUser: Couldn't find type User in any of the schemas.
    at collectNode (C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-import\src\definition.ts:154:15)    
    at C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-import\src\definition.ts:135:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at collectNewTypeDefinitions (C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-import\src\definition.ts:134:26)
    at Object.completeDefinitionPool (C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-import\src\definition.ts:49:39)
    at Object.importSchema (C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-import\src\index.ts:127:18) 
    at mergeTypeDefs (C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-yoga\src\index.ts:456:14)
    at C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-yoga\src\index.ts:472:32
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at mergeTypeDefs (C:\Websites\Learning-GraphQL - Local Copy\graphql-bootcamp\graphql-basics\node_modules\graphql-yoga\src\index.ts:471:21)
```

As you can see, it says it can't find one of my types (User), but I do have it in the User.graphql schema file.  When I have everything in just one file and pass that file only as the typeDefs, it works fine. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Saying something isn't working isn't particularly helpful -- if you're seeing an error, you should edit your question to include the full error message. Passing in an array of paths should work just fine, but you probably need absolute file paths, not relative ones, since your code is compiled.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new to Stack Overflow. I've added more detail.  I've tried absolute paths, but it still fails with the error listed above.

Answer (score 1):

```
const typeDefs = [  
  './schemas/query.graphql',   
  './schemas/mutation.graphql',  
  './schemas/user.graphql'  
];
```

this is only an array of strings

from docs:

> typeDefs  - String or Function or DocumentNode or array of previous

you can make something like:

```
import Query from './schemas/query.graphql'
import Mutation from './schemas/mutation.graphql'
import User from './schemas/user.graphql'

const typeDefs = [Query, Mutation, User];
```

config required: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#webpack-preprocessing-with-graphql-tagloader

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I'm getting parsing errors from the file. I'm thinking it's because it's thinking it's a JS file?

Comment: try this method: https://medium.com/@choudlet/how-to-combine-graphql-type-definitions-quickly-and-easily-with-apollo-server-c96c4d9a7ea1

Comment: the first method is from https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/21c2c5f27ee86627ce1acd010f238817aac71f46/modules/core/server-ts/api/schema.ts - `rootSchemaDef` imported from raw .graphql file into array

Comment: another solution: https://openbase.io/js/merge-graphql-schemas